# How to find a substring with a partially fixed pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string `var str = aklsjdfoiueori;ja;lkdsjf;lasdjf_something.js;akdfjl;kj`

I'm looking for whatever is in front of `.js`, but before the underscore. So I want to do something like `/_[A-Za-z].js/`, but `str.match(pattern)` returns null.

What is needed to have an output of `something.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var str = 'aklsjdfoiueori;ja;lkdsjf;lasdjf_something.js;akdfjl;kj';

var repl = str.replace(/_\w*\.js;.*/, '')
//=> aklsjdfoiueori;ja;lkdsjf;lasdjf
```

`_\w*\.js;.*` will find `_` followed by 0 or more word chars and `.js` and anything after that.

If you need `something.js` then use a capturing group:

**.replace:**

```
var jsname = str.replace(/.*_(\w*\.js);.*/, '$1')
//=> something.js
```

**.match:**

```
var jsname = str.match(/_(\w*\.js)/)[1];
//=> something.js
```

Comment: what is the reason for using the asterik?

Comment: * means: 0 or more times what comes before, in this case a . which means 'any character'

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'aklsjdfoiueori;ja;lkdsjf;lasdjf_something.js;akdfjl;kj'
str.replace(/.*_(.*).js.*/,'$1') // or str.match(/.*_(.*).js.*/)[1]
```

this will return `something`, is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern should be

```
/_[A-Za-z]+.js/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include the underscore, I'd use this

```
/[^_]+\.js/
```

Basically, match a series of characters that isn't an underscore until you hit .js